# Obsolete. Use the Open() method that takes a passphrase.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I used this code to open SPfarm 2010 :

```
SPFarm.Open(builder, log, secureStr);
```

but this exception shows up:

```
Obsolete. Use the Open() method that takes a passphrase.
```

I didint inderstande what dose it mean or how to resolve it .
i found this link :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms196945(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imen,

If you look at the below:
[SPFarm.Open method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.open.aspx)

You can use the first two Open Methods.. The rest of the two are Obsolete.

Comment: It works, thanks Arsalan Adam Khatri, you need to enter a Passphrase

Answer (score 1):

You are using 3 parameters in open which is Obsolete. use only 2 parameters inside open

```
SPFarm.Open(builder, secureStr);
```

Comment: It works, thanks Ashish, you need to enter a Passphrase